# Проблема с сеткой bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему `footer` залазит в правую колонку?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="row" style="background: #FA0">Header</div>
    <!--Main-->
    <div class="row" style="background: #AF9">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Left</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Main</div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">Right<div>
    </div>
    <!--Footer-->
    <div class="row" style="background: #FFA">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не закрыт `div` с текстом `right`

Comment: нда) стыдно такие вопросы задавать)